# Is there any way to check, in PHP, that whether any email is active or not?

Tags: php, email

Is there any way to check (through PHP) that whether any given email address is active (means is it currently being used & opened by anyone) or not (means it is blocked or no one uses/opens it, it's inactive)?

Regards & Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about an E-Mail server you host yourself or something like Google Mail?

Comment: Short answer no, email is so transient that it is very difficult to confirm whether or not an email is exists.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth I am talking about external servers like Google, Yahoo or Hotmail etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but have to use an API to an external service

There are a few email validation api's out there, data8 got one. http://www.data-8.co.uk/integr8/services/email_validation.aspx

Here is a sample

```
function IsValid($email, $level)
{
  $params = array(
    "username" => "your-username",
    "password" => "your-password",
    "email" => $email,
    "level" => $level,
    "options" => $options
  );
  $client = new SoapClient("http://webservices.data-8.co.uk/EmailValidation.asmx?WSDL");
  $result = $client->IsValid($params);
  if ($result->IsValidResult->Status->Success == 0)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $result->IsValidResult->Status->ErrorMessage;
  }
  else
  {
    // TODO: Process method results here.
    // Results can be extracted from the following fields:
    // $result->IsValidResult->Result
    //   Contains a status code indicating if the email address could be validated.
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmmmm, kind of, but this checks only whether the *domain* of the E-Mail address is live and active, and maybe the general existence of the E-Mail address on that server. It does not tell you whether a *specific* E-Mail address on that domain is in use, whether a user has access to it, etc.

Comment: It verifies the stated e-mail but like you say it's never 100% way to be sure, "Valid; According to the selected level of validation, the email address appears to be valid. This is not an absolute guarantee that emails sent to this address will be delivered and read."

Comment: Yes, my task is that to check that whether a user has access to it or not?

Comment: So you want to check if you can log in to an email account or not?

Comment: No actually I am trying to develop Mailing-List software, so I want to send emails to only those emails which are active and in use.

Comment: Is that Web Service API free or payed?

Comment: The one I posted is payed , but there should be several few. I choose this one cause of it's clear example.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to check (through PHP) that whether any given email address is active (means is it currently being used & opened by anyone) or not (means it is blocked or no one uses/opens it, it's inactive)?

No.

The only way to be sure is to send an E-Mail to the address, not get a bounce message, and get some kind of reply back (like an answer, or the user clicking a unique link in the E-Mail, or an image with a unique URL being opened [this is frowned upon though, and blocked by many E-Mail clients], or a read receipt). None of these methods is foolproof, though, so you can never tell for 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking if the email user enters is valid or not!! if this is the case then you should use nslookup for unix-based operating system with help of exec.. here is a small function for that: (i am checking if the domain is correct or not)

```
function myCheckDNSRR($email)
{
      list($userName, $hostName) = split("@", $email); 
$recType = '';
if(!empty($hostName)) {
   if( $recType == '' ) $recType = "MX";

   exec("nslookup -type=$recType $hostName", $result);
   // check each line to find the one that starts with the host
   // name. If it exists then the function succeeded.

   foreach ($result as $line) {
     if(eregi("^$hostName",$line)) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   // otherwise there was no mail handler for the domain
   return false;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: PHP has an own function checkdnsrr ;)